# Access anonymous function objects from the console

Tags: javascript, console

I know that if I declare an object like:

```
var myObj = {
  prop1 : 1,
  prop2 : 2
}
```

I can access and *manipulate* it from the console by typing `myObj`.

If I wrap it in an anonymous self-executing function, can I still access it from the console?

```
(function(){
  var myObj = {
    prop1 : 1,
    prop2 : 2
  }
})();
```

Comment: I believe not, that's the point of anonymous functions :)

Comment: Why don't you try and tell us ?

Comment: @Ricardo - I have been trying, and as far as I'm aware it's not possible, but there are always secret ins-and-outs of things and if you don't ask, you may never know. This question is more for knowledge than actually being able to apply it to something useful.

Comment: If you add a breakpoint in the JavaScript console and check the local variables, you *could* access it.

Comment: You could assign it to a var although thats probably not what you're after... var anon = (function{})();

Comment: Why donn't you just log from inside the anon function? And if not, why not just return something from it and log after? You example has no point at all.

Comment: I'm not looking to *log* anything. Quite often during development I assign variables that are inside anonymous functions to the `window` object, so I can manipulate them in the console directly (I'm not talking about *logging*, I'm talking about *manipulating*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably can.

For example in Chrome, you can insert a breakpoint at the correct position, then you can access (and manipulate) it.

[image]

(A fun fact of this screenshot is that your anonymous function is actually inside another anonymous function)

For Firefox I believe FireBug can do the job. IE8+ also has the functionality.